# Les Québécois utilisent-ils l'échelle longue ou l'échelle courte pour les nombres ?

Tags: nombres, québec

En France, on utilise l’échelle longue (e.g. l’anglais *1 billion* = le français 1 milliard), mais au Québec, utilise-t-on l’échelle longue, ou l’échelle courte (e.g. l’anglais *1 billion* = le français 1 billion) comme dans le reste de l’Amérique du Nord ?

Comment: Tu pourrais mettre des chiffres à côté pour les ignards comme moi? C'est quoi un billion quand c'est pas un milliard ?

Comment: @Benjol c'est un peu l'objet de la question

Comment: échelle courte : suffixes "ion" seulement => 1 million, 1 billion = 1000 millions, 1 trillion = 1000 billions… — échelle longue : suffixes alternés "ion" et "iard" => 1 million, 1 milliard = 1000 millions, 1 billion = 1000 milliards, 1 billiard = 1000 billions…

Comment: A priori, la tradition anglophone du Canada est plus proche de l'anglais britannique (qui utilisait "l'échelle longue" jusqu'à peu) que de l'anglais américain... En passant, l'usage de l'échelle longue est en voie d'extinction au Royaume Uni depuis un certain temps (cf. [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/billion-and-other-large-numbers)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia ne mentionne aucune différence de sens au Québec.

En français, un *[milliard](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milliard)* vaut mille millions, soit 10<sup>9</sup> (préfixe *[giga](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giga)*)

Un *[billion](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion)* vaut mille milliards, soit 10<sup>12</sup> (préfixe *[téra](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9ra)*).

A noter que le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/billion) mentionne que *billion* est un vieux synonyme de milliard, mais l'exemple datant de 1935 est sans doute plutôt du à une mauvaise traduction de l'anglais ; d'autant que la [section étymologique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/billion) fait remonter la signification *mille milliers de millions* de *billion* à 1721.

La page décrivant les [échelles longue et courte](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89chelles_longue_et_courte) précise bien que, si l'échelle courte est utilisée au Canada, les Canadiens francophones utilisent eux l'échelle longue.

A lire aussi, la page wikipedia sur le [nom des grands nombres](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_des_grands_nombres).

J'imagine que l'utilisation de préfixes pourrait parfois être un moyen d'éviter la confusion avec des anglophones, mais il reste difficile de parler en téramètres plutôt qu'en milliards de kilomètres.

Comment: _Billion_ comme vieux synonyme de _milliard_ est vraisemblablement dû au fait que les échelles longues et courtes ont été en concurrence en France.

Comment: Oui, c'est ce que la page sur les échelles semble impliquer aussi. Et l'échelle longue a gagné, mais les anglophones ne l'ont pas remarqué.

Comment: Mille millions de mille milliards de mille sabords :-)

Comment: Amusant, les dictionnaires de l'Académie française ne donnent que mille millions comme valeur, sauf le dernier qui indique _selon un décret de 1961, le mot « Billion » a reçu une nouvelle valeur, à savoir un million de millions, qui n'est pas entrée dans l'usage._

Comment: Effectivement, je n'avais pas vérifié ça. La version 8 renvoyait froidement à _milliard_.

Answer (score 4):

Le [Grand dictionnaire terminologique](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/gdt.html) définit billion comme

> Mille milliards, soit le chiffre 1 suivi de 12 zéros (10<sup>12</sup>).

C'est donc bien l'[échelle longue](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89chelles_longue_et_courte) en français, même au Québec. Une note signale une confusion possible avec l'anglais américain *billion*¹.

La [Banque de données terminologique du gouvernement du Canada (TERMIUM Plus)](http://btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra) définit quant à elle [*billion*](http://btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=billion&comencsrch.x=12&comencsrch.y=10&i=1) comme 10<sup>9</sup> en anglais d'amérique du nord et 10<sup>12</sup> en anglais britannique² et en français. Pour le gouvernement du Canada, [l'échelle courte est un anglicisme](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/typographie-typography/billions-fra.html).

Et au-delà de ces sources normatives, il semble bien qu'en pratique [les Québecois utilisent bien l'échelle longue](http://www.leblogueduql.org/2009/10/un-billion-de-dollars-%C3%A0-quoi-%C3%A7a-peut-bien-ressembler.html), [en général](http://forums.quebecit.net/topic/1797-youtube-a-une-valleur-de-1-billion/).

¹ 
<sub>Le Gdt distingue le français *billion* de l'anglais canadien *billion*. Pourtant le mot anglais signifie aujourd'hui 10<sup>9</sup> au Canada, et ce depuis encore plus longtemps qu'en Grande-Bretagne où le sens 10<sup>12</sup> a presque disparu. Comme quoi le gouvernement du Québec n'est pas une bonne référence en matière d'anglais.</sub>

² 
<sub>Mais voir la note 1.</sub>

Comment: En tant que Britannique, je dois toi corriger ici; l'échelle longue n'est pas utilisé en Grande-Bretagne plus, sauf comme un terme archaïque.  On utilise ici l'échelle courte partout.

Comment: @Jez I don't claim that Britain uses the long scale, I claim that the Canadian government claims so. Maybe one of my sentences is unclear, what made you think I endorsed their assessment?

Comment: The fact that you chose to mention their claim and not contradict it kinda implies that you are agreeing.

Answer (score 1):

L'échelle longue est généralement utilisée, mais dans certains domaines d'affaire plus anglophone comme la finance par exemple, il arrive souvent que quelqu'un emploie « billion » pour exprimer 10^9.

*Note : Lorsque je dis que la finance est un domaine plus anglophone, j'entends par là que les livres de références et les autres ressources sont souvent en anglais, et que le vocabulaire est souvent massacré par le fait même. Par exemple, on entend souvent « Équité » comme traduction pour « Equity » alors qu'il s'agit en fait de « Capitaux Propres ».*

Answer (score 0):

Au Québec, le terme billion est utilisé pour mille milliards en effet. Ensuite, mille billions est un billiard, trillion, trilliard, etc. Je crois que c'est ce qu'on appelle l'échelle longue.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien ta réponse. Tu peux reformuler ?

Comment: Au Québec, on utilise le mot "milliard" pour le même nombre que les américains anglais utilisent le mot "billion".

Comment: @Narvath, la question est "quelle est la valeur de _billion_ en français au Québec (en France c'est bien fixé à mille milliards depuis environ le milieu du XXième siècle et avant c'était plus ou moins ambigu).

Comment: @Un francophone, Je m'excuse, je crois que j'ai mal lu la question alors, le terme billion est utilisé pour mille milliards en effet. Ensuite, mille billions est un billiard, trillion, trilliard, etc. Je crois que c'est ce qu'on appelle l'échelle longue.

Comment: C'est pas grave mais ça explique la confusion. L'usage sur SE est quand on constate une telle confusion soit d'éditer la réponse pour la recadrer (ce qui aurait un intérêt ici, on n'a que des réponses indirectes ou officielle, une confirmation de celles-ci par un Québécois est bienvenue), soit de l'effacer. Pour ce faire, tu as des liens `link|edit|delete|flag` immédiatement sous ta réponse.